# Prove that two random variables are independent in this specific case

Tags: distributions, random-variable, independence

Suppose we have three independent ($N \times 1)$ complex vectors $\mathbf{w}$, $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{f}$ be . Assume that $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are of unit norm and isotropically distributed. In addition, we assume that $\mathbf{e}$ is complex gaussian with zero mean and variance $= \sigma^2$.
We define $x=(\mathbf{w}^* \mathbf{f})^*$ and $y=\mathbf{e}^* \mathbf{f}$, where $(\cdot)^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose.

Can we claim that $x$ and $y$ are independent (complex) random variables? if yes, how to prove it ?

**Attempt 1:**
We know that $E[x]=E[y]=E[y^*]=0$.
If we take $N=2$ for example, we can write :
$Cov(x,y^*)=E[xy]=E[w_1e_1^*|f_1|^2+w_2e_2^*|f_2|^2+w_1f_1^*e_2^*f_2+w_2f_2^*e_1^*f_1]=0$.
So $x$ is independent of $y^*$ and thus of $y$ .

**Attempt 2:**
If we perform a change of  basis such that $\mathbf{f}=[1,0,\ldots,0]$, so for $N=2$ we get $x=w_1$ and $y=e_1^*$. Since $e_1$ and $w_1$ are independent, we can say that $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548820/if-x-mathbfw-mathbff-and-y-mathbfe-mathbff-can-we-claim), but it did not get any attention! I am not sure if this is the proper way to link these questions.

Comment: The preferred method is to flag your original post on [math.se] for migration here.  However, contrary to your assertion, it got plenty of attention, including excellent hints about the answer.  You should continue pursuing it there rather than re-posting it here.

Comment: Should I understand that my approach is incorrect ? and that $x$ and $y$ are not independent ? thank you!

Comment: As to your approach - does a covariance of 0 imply independence?

Comment: @jbowman Oh.. my fault. You are right! covariance$=0$ is just a neccessary condition for independence. Do you think they are not independent?

Comment: If we perform a change of basis such that $\mathbf{f}=[1, 0, \ldots, 0]^T$, so if $N=2$ we get $x=w_1$ and $y=e_1^*$. Since $w_1$ and $e_1$ are independent, we can claim that $x$ and $y$ are independent.  What's about this approach? thx for your time!